# Variable Initialization error in constructor in ts file Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my app.component.html file

### PL Auth

**Username:** 
      
    
      **Password :** 
      
      
      Generate OTP
    
      
      **Enter OTP :** 
      
      
      Login

This is my app.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  submitted = false;
  userName = '';

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  constructor(private http: Http;) { }

  private generateOtp(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/generateotp/'+this.userName)
    .subscribe(
      (res:Response)=> {
        const otpCheck = res.json();
        console.log(otpCheck);
      }
    )
  }

  generateOtpSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.generateOtp();
  }
}
```

This is my app.module.ts file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [Http],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Whenever I tried to initialize any variables in `constructor(private http: Http;) { }` present in app.component.ts file I'm getting this error in browser console and page is not loading.

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Http -> ConnectionBackend]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Http -> ConnectionBackend]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ConnectionBackend!
```

Internal Error pic :

[image: Internal error in browser console]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the newer Angular versions (starting from 4.3) you need to import `HttpClientModule` and add it into the imports, you don't need to provide anything separately. Also notice that it is in the `@angular/common/http`. The class which you need to use for requests is called `HttpClient`. Use it instead of `Http`.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule 
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But you if you want still to use `Http`, which I don't offer - you need to import the `HttpModule` from `@angular/http` and add it into the imports. Still you don't need to add anything separately into the providers.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule 
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I tried previously but still I'm getting this issue

Comment: I have edited. Try it. `HttpClient` with `HttpClientModule`

Comment: I added the picture. Please refer once.

Comment: Your issue is related to `not imported HttpModule or HttpClientModule`. Try again. Stop and `ng serve` again